# How to delete rows other than a random row on a table(Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get data from the user and put it into the table by collating, I want to show a random line from the table I want to delete the other rows

```js
function bilgi(){

          var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (allobjs.length - 1) ) + 1;
          if (allobjs[random].id != 'blank'){
            allobjs[random].animate({fill: 'rgb(19, 167, 236)'}, 1000);
            $(function() {
              $.getJSON('/static/yer.json', function(data) {
                var deger = $("input[name=deger]").val()
                var al = deger.split(",")


                $.each(data, function(i, f) {
                    if(f.plaka == random){
                      var tblRow = "<tr>" +
                        "<td>" + "<img class='aaa'src='/static/bayrak.jpg' alt='' />" + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + deger + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + f.yerler + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + f.bolge + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + f.ili + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + f.teskilati + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + f.acm + "</td>" +
      "</tr>"
                      $("tbody").append(tblRow);
                    }
                });

              $("tbody tr").hide()
              var toplam= $("tbody tr").size()
              ratgel=Math.floor(Math.random() * toplam);
              $("tbody tr").eq(ratgel).show(1000)
              });
             });
        }}
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript add class NOSHOW to each tr you want to hide Then using css .NOSHOW{display:none;} If you want a complete solution show your html.

something like the following might work:

At the start of your function add the following:

```
var tr = getElementsByTagName('tr');
for(var i = 0; i < tr.length;i++){
   tr[i].className += "noshow";
}
```

then in you html add:

```
<style>
   .noshow{
      display:none;
   }
</style>
```

This should work as you then append the row you want to the end of the table.

Later, when you want to display the entire table again you can use:

```
 element.classList.remove("noshow");
```

Comment: I didn't understand where to add. Can you show me at https://paste.ubuntu.com/

Comment: right after this:  function bilgi(){ for the js and in your html in the head tag for the css  and get rid of $("tbody tr").hide()
              var toplam= $("tbody tr").size()
              ratgel=Math.floor(Math.random() * toplam);
              $("tbody tr").eq(ratgel).show(1000)

Comment: "noshow" should have a leading space (i.e. " noshow") in case the tr already has a class